# Accessing new photos saved within the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

It's my first question, so sorry if I make any mistake.

I have an Objective-C application doing basically: Showing photos taken earlier, taking and saving new photos.

In my first view I have this code working to show earlier photos inside a collection view:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    imagePaths = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:documentsDirectory] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
    imageCount = imagePaths.count;
}
```

And,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    imagePaths = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:documentsDirectory] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
    imageCount = imagePaths.count;
    //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageCount]);
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Creating Collection view with following methods:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return imageCount;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PictureCollectionViewCell *cell = (PictureCollectionViewCell *) [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PictureCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];

    cell.imageView.image = image;
    return cell;
}


-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```

And in another view, where I save the taken photo, i have this:

```
-(void) savePhotoMethod{    
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",photoIndex ];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",fileName]];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imageData attributes:nil];


    /*if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath])
{
    NSLog(@"succes!!");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *imagePaths = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:documentsDirectory] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
    int imageCount = imagePaths.count;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageCount]);

    } I also have his control, so I know the photo is actually saved successfully, but the imageCount is still showing me the number like last photo is not counted.*/


    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My problem is, The first view is showing the earlier photos successfully when app first starts. But after taking a new photo, saving it and returning to the first view; `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods cannot find the last saved photo. Though when I exit the app and re-launch it again, I can see the last photos too.

Any ideas regarding to this problem or ideas to make my app more efficient is welcomed!

Comment: what is imagecount ? is it int variable which count number of photots?

Comment: @AshishThakkar Exactly, using it for - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return imageCount;
}

Comment: //imageCount = imagePaths.count;
then uncomment this line in viewWillAppear and check it

Comment: @AshishThakkar Still not working, actually that line was not commented in my code, probably just miss commented it while posting here, so thats not the problem

Comment: @BuğraCansınGöz can you add the code where the image is added to the view.

Comment: @rob180 edited as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
-(void) savePhotoMethod
{   
    dispatch_queue_t mainThreadQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainThreadQueue, ^{

       NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
       NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",photoIndex ];
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",fileName]];

       NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    });

}
```

Edit viewwillAppear method

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(1.0, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime,

                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),

                   ^(void) {

                      paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
imagePaths = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:documentsDirectory] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
imageCount = imagePaths.count;
//NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageCount]);
[_collectionView reloadData];
                   });


}
```

Comment: Please, add a description of the solution you're proposing.

Comment: @il_raffa I am answering for a problem " The first view is showing the earlier photos successfully when app first starts. But after taking a new photo, saving it and returning to the first view; viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods cannot find the last saved photo. Though when I exit the app and re-launch it again, I can see the last photos too."

Comment: @Wos Unfortunately, it's still not working. Same problem, I have to exit then relaunch to see all the photos

Comment: @BuğraCansınGöz May I know "viewWillAppear" is call when you back "popToRootViewControllerAnimated"?

Comment: @Wos Yes, it is called succesfully so [_collectionView reloadData] works and collectionView methods work again too.

Comment: @BuğraCansınGöz I edit my answer, try that. Let me know if it is work or not.

Comment: @Wos I declared double delayInSeconds = 2.0; at the beginnig of your viewWillAppear method, but no change buddy

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way:

```
-(void) savePhotoMethod
{
NSOperationQueue *opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[opQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
 {
 NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
   NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",photoIndex ];
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",fileName]];

   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
 // ok, now do UI stuff in the main queue

 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
  {
      [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }];
```

}  ]  ;
    }

hope it will solve your problem